# Map Marker with Muliline Info Window

Tags: java, google-maps, android-studio, marker

The text in the follow code is not displayed completely within the info window (shown below):

```
mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(the_local_user2).title("My Title").snippet("My Snippet"+"\n"+"1st Line Text"+"\n"+"2nd Line Text"+"\n"+"3rd Line Text")
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED)));
```

[image]

I would like it to look similar to this:

[image]

I found [Marker-Plugins SDK](https://github.com/mapsplugin/cordova-plugin-googlemaps-doc/blob/master/v1.4.0/class/Marker/README.md), but I do not know if it is good or not.

How can I get the info window to display multiline text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a [custom info window](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/infowindows#custom_info_windows) with multiline text.

To do this all you have to do is implement `GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter` in your `Activity` and inflate a custom `View` for the info window. Then call `GoogleMap#setInfoWindowAdapter`.

```
public class MapActivity extends AppCompatActivity imeplements OnMapReadyCallback, GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter {

    private GoogleMap mGoogleMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstaceState);
        setContentView(r.layout.activity_map);

        SupportMapFragment fragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        fragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        googleMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(this);
        mGoogleMap = googleMap;
    }

    @Override
    public View getInfoWindow(Marker marker) {
        return null; // Use default info window background
    }

    @Override
    public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {
        View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.info_window_multiline, null);

        TextView titleTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title);
        TextView snippetTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.snippet);

        titleTextView.setText(marker.getTitle());
        snippetTextView.setText(marker.getSnippet());

        return view;
    }

}
```

Also, the [Cordova GoogleMaps Plugin](https://github.com/mapsplugin/cordova-plugin-googlemaps-doc) is for applications that use either the [Cordova](http://cordova.apache.org/) or [PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com/) development frameworks; not for native Android development. The [Google Maps Android API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/) is meant for native development; which it seems you are already making use of. Do not confuse the two.